# Should a service call another service or should it fetch it's own data

Tags: swift, oop

I have a **message service** that is responsible for pushing the correct messages to a `UITableView`. Some of these messages are system messages and whilst their content is generic they should for example, include a user's name.

This data is currently requested and available via my **profile service**.

I have been trying to write a service per API, but now I am wondering, should I inject my profile service into message service? I feel this violates **SOLID** if my service starts doing more than just talking to messages, but then as I understand, a service should not depend on another?

Apologies for the broad question, I am still learning everyday,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Message Service can call your Profile Service, that does not violate any principles, **however your Message Service should not break if the underlying code in your Profile Service changes**.

I would not have your Message Service talk to your Profile API.

Imagine if the contract or implementation of your Profile API changed, now your Message Service AND Profile Service potentially are broken.

By having your Message Service talk to your Profile Service, you can be sure (through unit / integration tests) any changes to your API / Service do not break your other services and views.